# Autoplay no reproduce el video

Tags: javascript, html, html5, video

Tengo una duda con el siguiente codigo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Video</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  function iniciar() {
  video=document.getElementById('video');
  video.addEventListener('ended',reproducir,false);
     }

  function reproducir() {
          video.setAttribute('src', 'musica2.mp4')
  }
  window.addEventListener('load',iniciar,false);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <section>
  <video controls autoplay muted id="video" width="720" height="400" 
        c src="musica.mp4">
        </video>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Si le quito el atributo muted al tag 'video' , ya no me reproduce este cuando la pagina esta cargada(el atributo autoplay no funciona). A que se debe esto, y como podría hacer que el video se reproduzca cuando la pagina cargue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google decidió que era molesto que, al entrar a una página web, un video pudiese reproducirse automáticamente. Así que Chrome [es bastante restrictivo al respecto](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). Traducción automática de la web:

> Como habrás notado , los navegadores web están adoptando políticas de
>   reproducción automática más estrictas para mejorar la experiencia del
>   usuario, minimizar los incentivos para instalar bloqueadores de
>   anuncios y reducir el consumo de datos en redes caras y / o
>   restringidas. Estos cambios están destinados a dar un mayor control de
>   la reproducción a los usuarios y beneficiar a los editores con casos
>   de uso legítimos.
>
> Las políticas de reproducción automática de Chrome son simples:
>
> - **La reproducción automática silenciada siempre está permitida**.
> - Reproducción automática con sonido está permitido si:
>
>   - El usuario ha interactuado con el dominio (haga clic, toque, etc.).
>   - En el escritorio, se ha cruzado el umbral del Índice de interacción con los medios del usuario , lo que significa que el
>       usuario ya ha reproducido video con sonido.
>   - En dispositivos móviles, el usuario ha agregado el sitio a su pantalla de inicio.
> - Los marcos superiores pueden delegar permisos de reproducción automática a sus iframes para permitir la reproducción automática con
>     sonido.
>
> ### Índice de interacción con los medios (MEI, de *Media Engagement Index*)
>
> El MEI mide la propensión de un individuo a consumir medios en un
>   sitio. El enfoque actual de Chrome es una proporción de visitas a
>   eventos significativos de reproducción de medios por origen:
>
> - El consumo del medio (audio / video) debe ser mayor a 7 segundos.
> - El audio debe estar presente y no silenciado.
> - La pestaña con video está activa.
> - El tamaño del video (en px) debe ser mayor a 200x140.
>
> A partir de eso, Chrome calcula una puntuación de participación de
>   medios que es más alta en los sitios donde se reproducen los medios de
>   forma periódica. Cuando es lo suficientemente alto, la reproducción
>   multimedia solo se puede reproducir automáticamente en el escritorio.
>
> El MEI del usuario está disponible en la página interna `chrome://media-engagement`.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentar reproducirlo automaticamente utilizando Javascript cuando cargue la página.

Seria algo asi:

HTML:

```
<video id="video" width="720" height="400" src=".../.mp4">
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {
  let vid = document.getElementById("video"); 

  function playVid() { 
    vid.play(); 
  } 

  function pauseVid() { 
    vid.pause(); 
  }
})();
```

Saludos!

Comment: Chrome lo bloqueará igualmente, cualquier intento de ejecutar un vídeo sin interacción explícita del usuario y sin cumplir las restricciones debidas será cancelado.

Comment: Pero Youtube ejecuta los vídeos automáticamente cuando entras a un vídeo (En realidad, cuando abrís la pestaña donde esta el vídeo. Quizás utilizar el mismo evento?)

Comment: YouTube cumple el MEI (como es de esperar, al ser un servicio de Google).

Answer (score 1):

mmm... no soy un experto en la materia, pero lo unico que le falta al codigo para que se ejecute el autoplay es incluir en el atributo "src" una url completa. Al estar incompleta no carga el video y sin carga no hay play.

**Nota personal**: Uso el atibuto autoplay de la siguiente manera: autoplay="autoplay" y recomiendo incluir en todo momento dentro del atributo "src" la url completa, sin importar si el video se encuentra en la misma carpeta raiz.

```html
<video controls autoplay muted id="video" width="300" height="150" src="https://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg"></video>
```