# No funciona video mp4 de fondo en navegador Brave

Tags: html5, css3, video, navegador-web

Me funciona perfectamente en Chrome y Edge. No lo he probado en Firefox. 
No os trascribo el código porque funciona perfectamente en los demás y considero que tiene que ser algún asunto de seguridad. ¿No?

Añado el código:

En el Body:

```
 <video src="static/video/video_web_govern_bucle_aigua_4_3.mp4" autoplay loop muted poster="static/img/poster.png">
    </video>
```

El css:

```
video {
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;

}
```

Comment: Puede ser un problema con la configuración del navegador (creo que Brave viene con autoplay deshabilitado por defecto). Pero para poder ayudarte mejor, por favor, comparte algo más de información: ¿cuál es el código de lo que intentas? ¿te sale algún error en Brave que no aparece en los otros navegadores? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro por tu respuesta. Código añadido. No añadí código porque funciona bien en otros navegadores y creo que se trata de algún problema de configuración. El vídeo está deshabilitado por defecto en el navegador Brave para android, ahí sé habilitarlo, pero no encuentro esa opción en la versión para windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brave es [más estricto que Chrome](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172292/autoplay-no-reproduce-el-video/172293#172293) y actualmente no permite el autoplay ni siquiera en modo *muted* (sin audio). Actualmente (Diciembre de 2019) hay una petición abierta en Github pidiendo [que se permita o que se clarifique si no se va a permitir ahora ni en el futuro](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/3233).

También hay otra petición para permitir el autoplay en las opciones del navegador, porque ahora mismo [sólo se puede aceptar página por página](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/3623)