# Video no carga en mi página web

Tags: html, html5, html-video

Buenos días comunidad,

Vuelvo con otra pequeña duda, en mi página web cargo un vídeo con tres formatos distintos *mp4*, *webm* y *ogv*. Cuando entro a la página, se guarda el lugar para el video pero no ocurre nada, sin embargo cuando hago click derecho y volver a cargar sobre el video, recarga la página y lo muestra.

Quisiera saber a que ocurre este error.

```html
<video autoplay loop poster="bg-talleres.jpg">
   <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="video/video.webm" type="video/webm">
   <source src="video/video.ogv" type="video/ogg">  
</video>
```

Comment: Responde [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172293/146637) a tu pregunta??

Answer (score 1):

trata de agregar los atributos

- width=""
- height=""

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Video</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop poster="bg-talleres.jpg" autoplay controls>
        <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/video.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="video/video.ogv" type="video/ogg">  
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

-> En esta pagina puedes ver mas sobre el tema:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp